# Application Insights initialization by code in Windows Phone fails

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, azure-application-insights

we are trying to get Application Insights in our apps work. If I choose the automatic configuration "Add Application Insights Telemetry" it works, but if I try to add it by the following code, it does not:

```
        TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey;
        TelemetryClient tc = new TelemetryClient();

        tc.TrackEvent("Testevent Windows Phone");
```

There are no exceptions or error messages thrown, but it also does not show events in the Visual Studio window or the azure portal.

What is wrong with this code? Is it the adding of the Instrumentation key? I found it [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-custom-events-metrics-api/#dynamic-ikey). I need to add the Instrumentation key and initialization complete dynamically, because we need to use it in one of our cordova applications as a plugin (which is already working for Android).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what version of the sdk are you using?  the newest (1.1) versions do wireup a different way, and doesn't require using a config file.  If you have a config file, and you're setting the iKey from code, make sure you remove the `<InstrumentationKey>blah</InstrumentationKey>` thing from the config file.

Comment: I am using the current version from NuGet which is 1.1.0. I do not have a config file in my project. Can you provide a link on how the setup has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that the code in my question was ok! Maybe some delay in the Azure Portal, but now the events arrive.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this documentation:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-get-started/

In short:
1. Add *ApplicationInsight.config* with just the Instrumentation Key.
2. Add this line `WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync();` as the first line in the App constructor. 
3. Create telemetry client and call the track methods.

--Izik

Comment: I can't do it like that. As i said i want to use dynamic configuration since im running a cordova app. We don't want to copy config files with the plugin. Additionally it's not good and easy to modify the App.xaml.cs provided by cordova.